# Intern functional tests: module request is missing

Tags: node.js, selenium, dojo, intern

I've tried setting up a minimal test demonstration, but I'm stuck when I try to run tests.

What I get is:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
Starting tunnel...
Error: Failed to load module request from /tmp/local-selenium-intern/request.js (parent: tests/functional)
  at <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:757:12>
  at <fs.js:207:20>
  at Object.oncomplete  <fs.js:107:15>
```

What I expect is that internal modules (such as `request` doesn't require any explicit configuration for them to load correctly).

I have this test configuration:

```
define({
    proxyPort: 9000,
    proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',
    capabilities: {
        'selenium-version': '2.35.0',
        'idle-timeout': 30
    },
    environments: [
        { browserName: 'firefox' },
        { browserName: 'chrome' }
    ],
    maxConcurrency: 3,
    useSauceConnect: false,
    webdriver: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 4444
    },
    loader: {
      // TODO: What to add here?
    },
    suites: [ 'tests/unit' ],
    functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional' ],
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

`tests/functional.js` contains this:

```
'use strict';

define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'request'
], function (registerSuite, assert, request) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'async demo',

        'async test': function () {
            var dfd = this.async(1000);

            request('http://example.com/test.json').then(dfd.callback(function (data) {
                assert.strictEqual(data, 'Hello world!');
            }), dfd.reject.bind(dfd));
        }
    });
});
```

(An example from interns own documentation.)

The example provided is very basic and can be tested by downloading the code below followed `npm install && npm start``:

https://github.com/mzedeler/local-selenium-intern/tree/request-broken

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your repository, I see you fixed the issue by using the `request` module from Intern's copy of Dojo. While this works, it's better to use your own copy of Dojo for your tests. Intern (the non-geezer version, at least) doesn't use standard Dojo, and makes no guarantees about the functionality therein. The current release of Dojo (1.10.0) is available through the npm repository, so it's easy to include as a project dependency.

Also, the test config in your project is a bit out of date. Specifically, the `webdriver` and `useSauceConnect` options have been replaced by `tunnel` and `tunnelOptions`. More information about the changes in Intern 2 is available in the [2.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/theintern/intern/releases/tag/2.0.0).